# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Description'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello everyone i am new in flutter. I am trying to take data from API. When i try to take, i can get the body but i cannot get the datas from into it. I get an error like "I/flutter ( 8981): type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Description'". Here is a screenshot for from my console when i run the code: [Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnXrO.jpg)

and here is my code:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:feedme_start/main.dart';
import 'package:feedme_start/model/AnaEkran_modeli.dart';
import 'package:feedme_start/model/branch_list.dart';
import 'package:feedme_start/model/restourantList.dart';
import 'package:feedme_start/widgets/Navigation_Drawer_Widget.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class restaurantPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const restaurantPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _restaurantPageState createState() => _restaurantPageState();
}

final datas = [];

final datas_oneri = [];

class _restaurantPageState extends State<restaurantPage> {
  int counter = 0;
  var personalResult;
  Future getapidata() async {
//orjinal api denemesi

    String url =
        "https://www.mobilonsoft.com/fpsapi/default.aspx?op=branch_list&firmuid=feedmekktc&device_id=web_20210813180900001&device_platform=4&lang=en";

    try {
      Response responsee = await get(Uri.parse(url)); //yanıtı alır
      if (responsee.statusCode == 200) {
        // yanıt onaylanırsa
        Map sonuc = jsonDecode(responsee.body); //içeriği alır
        print("apideki veriler ;");
        print(sonuc);
         **Branchlist liste = Branchlist.fromJson(sonuc);**
        print(liste.result.branchList.toString());
      } else {}
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      print("verileri çekerken hata oluştu");
    }

  


  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getapidata();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          leading: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyApp()));
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showSearch(context: context, delegate: dataSearch());
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: counter,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(personalResult.data[index].firstName +
                        " " +
                        personalResult.data[index].lastName),
                    subtitle: Text(personalResult.data[index].email),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage:
                          NetworkImage(personalResult.data[index].avatar),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class dataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    // actions for appbar
    return [
      IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            query = "";
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.clear))
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    // leading icon on the left of the app bar
    return IconButton(
      icon: AnimatedIcon(
          icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_arrow, progress: transitionAnimation),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, query);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // show some result based on the selection
    return Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Card(),
    );

    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    // show when someone searches for something
    final datasOnerisi = query.isEmpty
        ? datas_oneri
        : datas.where((p) => p.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          showResults(context);
        },
        leading: Icon(Icons.search),
        title: RichText(
          text: TextSpan(
              text: datasOnerisi[index].substring(0, query.length),
              style:
                  TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                    text: datasOnerisi[index].substring(query.length),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey))
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      itemCount: datasOnerisi.length,
    );
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Comment: On which line do you get this error?

Comment: i dont get any error. It's api response you can see it on picture... it sends the error to catch section and shows me this on console. When i put breakpoint it sends to the catch on " Branchlist liste = Branchlist.fromJson(sonuc);" it is starred on the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by changing my Model class... There were some mistakes about that. A 'string' was saved as'description' thats why it was giving this error. So i changed it with string and it solved. It was an little easy but sneaky mistake

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.